# Oracle TRANSLATE Not Returning Expected Result

Tags: oracle

We are trying to execute `TRANSLATE` on a couple hundred rows of data. We have a temporary table containing ID's to rows that need to be updated using `TRANSLATE`. The odd part is if we attempt to select say two rows, the command is executed properly and the information is updated. However, when we try to run it against 200 rows, it says that 200 rows were updated, but in inspecting the data, they have not been updated. Is there a limitation to the number of rows that can be updated using `TRANSLATE` in a single query?

We're doing something like:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A SET COLUMN_TO_UPDATE = 
TRANSLATE(COLUMN_TO_UPDATE,'ñ','n')
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TEMP_TABLE);
```

Comment: No, there isn't a limit. Have you inspected the data in a different session without `COMMIT`ting in the `UPDATE` session? (Common mistake, may as well ask). This won't really be possible to answer without test data, as no error message is returned and it /should/ just work. There is definitely something else in play here....

Comment: Thanks Phil. The DBA has been inspecting it in the same session without committing.

Comment: You do realise that `TRANSLATE()` replaces characters with one another & not whole strings? If you want to replace whole strings, use `REGEXP_REPLACE()`. By the way, just because it says `200 rows updated` doesn't mean that the `TRANSLATE()` function actually did anything. `COLUMN_TO_UPDATE` may have merely been updated to be the same as the previous value.

Comment: Sorry, I just included some random 'blahs' in my example. We are in fact replacing specific characters in our query.

Comment: In that case, this will be difficult to answer without copies of the data or another way to reproduce.

Comment: You've wandered back to the site since - has this been resolved? Always good to have an answer...

Comment: So we got some odd behavior. We were running a CSSCAN to determine if we were going to have some truncation issues. The initial scan told us that we had 200+ rows. After we ran the truncate command, we ran the scan and it decreased to 60. We ran the translate command on those 60 rows and nothing. However, when I then created a PL/SQL script and looped through each of the 60 rows and executed the exact same translate command, it updated the rows properly. The SCCAN results then said everything was fine. I can't really explain why that occurred but there nothing wrong with the translate command.

Answer (score -1):

Phil is right, "No, there isn't a limit", "it /should/ just work", and " this will be difficult to answer without copies of the data or another way to reproduce".  Here is a demonstration:

```
/*
drop table table_a;
drop table temp_table;
create table table_a as 
    (select level id, to_char(level) column_to_update from dual connect by level <=200);
create table temp_table as (select level id from dual connect by level <= 200);
update table_a set column_to_update='2ñ' where column_to_update='2';
*/

SELECT * FROM table_a;

UPDATE table_a SET column_to_update = TRANSLATE(COLUMN_TO_UPDATE,'ñ','n') 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TEMP_TABLE);

SELECT * FROM table_a;
```

You could try adding a WHERE clause to verify that `TRANSLATE` is actually changing rows.

```
UPDATE table_a SET column_to_update = TRANSLATE(COLUMN_TO_UPDATE,'ñ','n') 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TEMP_TABLE)
AND column_to_update <> TRANSLATE(COLUMN_TO_UPDATE,'ñ','n') ;
```

If this returns 200 rows then you might not be looking at the correct rows.  If it returns zero rows then the `TRANSLATE` function is not changing the data.